# Is it possible for a JavaScript array to contain itself?

Tags: javascript

In Ruby, [it's possible for an array to contain itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606734/what-are-recursive-arrays-good-for), making it a recursive array. Is it possible to put a JavaScript array inside itself as well?

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = "The next element of this array is the array itself."
```

Now how can I move `arr` into `arr[1]` so that the array contains itself recursively, (e. g., so that `arr[1]` is `arr`, `arr[1][1]` contains `arr`, `arr[1][1][1]` contains `arr`, etc.)?

Comment: Just set it to `arr`.  `arr[1] = arr`.

Comment: You can do it, but it will cause JSON.stringify to throw errors if you need to send it to a remote machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure:

```
var a = [1];
a.push(a);
```

They're the same object:

```
a[1] === a[1][1]  // true
```

And a convincing screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which desktop application or web application did that screenshot come from?

Comment: Since `a[1] === a[1][1] === a[1][1][1]` is actually false, it might make more sense to show it on two lines: `a[1] === a[1][1] // true` and `a[1] === a[1][1][1]  // true`

Comment: @AndersonGreen That looks like a screenshot of Chrome's console.

Comment: @AndersonGreen seems like Google Developer Tools )

Comment: @Paulpro: Thanks. Sometimes you forget that JavaScript isn't Python.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Looks like the console from Developer tools (F12) in Chrome Browser.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Sounds like it's time for you to learn how to use a debugger...  I don't know how you can survive for an instant without one!

Comment: I think I just headsploded.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, sure:

```
var x = [];
x.push(x);
console.log(x[0] === x); // true
```