# Why does Ruby allow me to push an array on itself?

Tags: ruby, arrays

This code is valid in Ruby

```
a = [5,10,15]
[5,10,15]
a.push a
[5,10,15,[...]]
```

Resulting in the fourth array slot pointing to the array itself, (seemingly) infinitely. Why does Ruby allow this and does the functionality offer any practical applications?

Comment: The simplest example I can think of is a garbage collector - you keep a list of references to every object in memory (including that list!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in Ruby everything is an object, variables just point to the objects (more strictly speaking, memory locations). An array is a collection of such a pointers, which means it can store a pointer to itself. It is not an extra feature added in Ruby, it would be actually an extra feature not to allow it.

As for application, check out "[What are recursive arrays good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606734/what-are-recursive-arrays-good-for)" (directed graph representation).

Note however, that such an array is not infinite:

```
a = []
a << a
a.length = 1
```

Comment: Are there any useful applications?

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby is a dynamic language, an array is, in essence, a collection of "any object" so you can push anything you want into it, including other arrays, including (in this case) a reference to itself.  It's like an `ArrayList<Object>` in Java, which can do the same thing (you can add it to itself, but why?)

It might be sometimes useful to have recursive structures, though nothing comes to mind.